# LWC - Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'contestRecords' of type 'LIST'

Tags: lightning-web-components

Ok, first time I am trying to create a LWC and I cannot figure out the error message I see in the browser log. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am trying to learn this so I can stop creating visualforce based solutions.

```
"Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'contestRecords' of type 'LIST'"
```

I have been using ChatGPT to help me create this and overall it has been very helpful in showing me how everting works but it hasn't been able to help me identify the solution to this issue.

One thing that is really throwing me is that I have enabled debug logs for both myself, as the LWC triggering user, and the Apex controller itself however it seems like the apex controller is never called as no logs are being created.

**HTML**

```
<!-- createContestRecord.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Award Performance Trophies">
        <div class='slds-var-m-around_medium'>
            <template for:each={contestRecords} for:item="record" for:index="index">
                <div key={record.Id} class="record-section">
                    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contest_Tracking__c" record-type-id="01280000000Br79AAC">
                        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-wrap">
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Related_to__c" required onchange={handleInputChange} data-index={index}></lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="User__c" required onchange={handleInputChange} data-index={index}></lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Trophy__c" required onchange={handleInputChange} data-index={index}></lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Trophy_Message__c" required onchange={handleInputChange} data-index={index}></lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Contest_Name__c" required onchange={handleInputChange} data-index={index}></lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-record-edit-form>
                </div>
            </template>
            <lightning-button label="Additional Trophy" onclick={addRecord} variant="success"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Save Trophies" onclick={createContestRecords} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
// createContestRecord.js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import createContestRecords from '@salesforce/apex/ContestController.createContestRecords';

export default class CreateContestRecord extends LightningElement {
    @track contestRecords = [{}];

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.contestRecords[index][event.target.fieldName] = event.detail.value;
    }

    addRecord() {
        this.contestRecords.push({});
    }

    createContestRecords() {
        // Validate required fields for all records
        const isValid = this.contestRecords.every(
            record => record.Related_to__c && record.Trophy__c && record.Trophy_Message__c && record.Contest_Name__c
        );
    
        if (isValid) {
            // Log the formatted data before making the call
            console.log('Formatted Records:', this.contestRecords);
    
            // Convert array of objects to the expected format (List<Map<String, String>>)
            const formattedRecords = this.contestRecords.map(record => {
                return {
                    Related_To__c: record.Related_to__c,
                    Trophy__c: record.Trophy__c,
                    Trophy_Message__c: record.Trophy_Message__c,
                    Contest_Name__c: record.Contest_Name__c,
                    User__c: record.User__c // Add other fields if needed
                };
            });
    
            // Call Apex method to create records
            createContestRecords({ contestRecords: formattedRecords })
                .then(result => {
                    // Handle success
                    console.log('Records created successfully:', result);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Handle error
                    console.error('Error creating records:', error);
                });
        } else {
            // Display an error message for missing required fields
            console.error('Please fill in all required fields for each record.');
        }
    }
}
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class ContestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createContestRecords(List<Map<String, String>> contestRecords) {
        List<Contest_Tracking__c> newRecords = new List<Contest_Tracking__c>();

        try {
            for (Map<String, String> recordData : contestRecords) {
                Contest_Tracking__c newRecord = new Contest_Tracking__c(
                    Related_To__c = recordData.get('Related_To__c'),
                    Trophy__c = recordData.get('Trophy__c'),
                    Trophy_Message__c = recordData.get('Trophy_Message__c'),
                    Contest_Name__c = recordData.get('Contest_Name__c'),
                    User__c = recordData.get('User__c'),
                    RecordTypeId = '01280000000Br79AAC'
                );

                newRecords.add(newRecord);
            }

            insert newRecords;
            System.debug('Records inserted successfully.');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error creating records: ' + e.getMessage());
            // Log any additional information about the exception if needed
            System.debug('Exception Type: ' + e.getTypeName());
            System.debug('Exception Message: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.debug('Exception Stack Trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString());
            throw e; // Re-throw the exception to propagate it to the Lightning web component
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is likely being thrown as the use of Maps to pass data to Apex methods isn't supported as per the docs here: [Call Apex Methods Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-call-imperative.html).

Instead, you will need to make sure that you're using an array of objects. In the case of code that you've supplied, it means you should be able to remove the section with the mapping of this.contestedRecords to formattedRecords like the below:

```
// createContestRecord.js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import createContestRecords from '@salesforce/apex/ContestController.createContestRecords';

export default class CreateContestRecord extends LightningElement {
    @track contestRecords = [{}];

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.contestRecords[index][event.target.fieldName] = event.detail.value;
    }

    addRecord() {
        this.contestRecords.push({});
    }

    createContestRecords() {
        // Validate required fields for all records
        const isValid = this.contestRecords.every(
            record => record.Related_to__c && record.Trophy__c && record.Trophy_Message__c && record.Contest_Name__c
        );
    
        if (isValid) {
            // Log the formatted data before making the call
            console.log('Formatted Records:', this.contestRecords);
    
            // Call Apex method to create records
            createContestRecords({ contestRecords: this.contestRecords })
                .then(result => {
                    // Handle success
                    console.log('Records created successfully:', result);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Handle error
                    console.error('Error creating records:', error);
                });
        } else {
            // Display an error message for missing required fields
            console.error('Please fill in all required fields for each record.');
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also need to update the Apex method itself to accept a List of records which means you also won't need to manually parse these like the supplied code.